# Turn off button moving

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to disable button moving after clicking on it ?

```
button
{
background:none;
border:0px;
}
```

I want button to seem like navigation bar item and need to disable animation during clicking the button.

Comment: You can cover it over with invisible div that will catch the click event.

Comment: try using a `div` or `span` element instead of fighting with the `button`

Comment: I need button for my JS action which moves me from one div to another one

Comment: JS actions can be binded to any DOM elements, not only buttons.

Comment: what do you mean by "moving after clicking"? Are you saying the clicking effect of button?

Comment: yea exactly, title of the button is little moving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also was looking to solve this issue and found that it was the padding that was making the button "animate". I had buttons with no background though so you may have to implement @user3481932's answer of adjusting the border and outline styles as well.

Comment: You're absolutely right! Padding was the problem. Thank you guys

Comment: Glad I could help. I remember looking around when I had the same problem and couldn't seem to find any answers. You should mark the answer as answered so the question can be closed.

Answer (score 2):

The animation of a button is caused by the border or outline of your button so if you specify a constant border and remove the outline, then no animation will occur.

```
button {
    outline: none;
    border: solid 1px #c5c5c5;
}
```

You may need to add `!important` to override click styles